# Do contractions (e.g. "don't") and full phrases (e.g. "do not") have the same meaning?

Tags: contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

What is the difference between "don't" and "do not" in the English literature as well as spoken English? Are they same?

The same question goes for "wouldn't" and "would not", "couldn't" and "could not".

Comment: I could say, "Don't joke about bombs at airports."  But I might say instead, "Do NOT joke about bombs at airports."  The uncontracted form "do not" is stronger and more serious, especially when you emphasize the "not".

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Arguably, that difference in nuance isn't because of the contraction itself, but rather the difference between formal and informal language (although in your defense, formal language does tend to avoid contractions more often than informal language. But that's correlation, not causation, as far as I'm aware). "I'm asking for you to visit me" versus "I am requesting for you to visit me". Same meaning, but nuanced interpretation as to the severity of the request.

Comment: @Flater: It sounds like you're agreeing with me, but your comment is written as if there is some kind of disagreement, so I am a bit unsure what you are actually trying to say. I'm also not sure what you mean by "correlation not causation". Surely if avoiding contractions makes our language more formal, then wanting to express something in a more formal register would mean that we choose to use fewer contractions? Isn't that a causal relationship?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: To clarify my earlier statement: the reason for the _serious_ tone is the _formal_ language. In this example, the formal language is distinguished by the lack of contractions (which means that the lack of contractions is an **indirect** consequence of wanting to carry a more serious tone and therefore intentionally wanting to sound more formal). So you're right about the specific example, but it would be more correct to say that the seriousness in the latter example **directly** stems from its formal phrasing.

Comment: @Flater: We can argue about cause of death all we want... I say that the man died because he was stabbed, and you say that the man died because of blood loss caused by the stab wound, and the death was only an "indirect consequence" of being stabbed. This is clearly not a disagreement of fact, instead, we are just using different levels of detail to explain things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Don't", "wouldn't" and "couldn't" are **contractions** of "do", "would" and "could" with "not".

From the [Wikipedia page on Contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29):

> An informal type of contraction occurs
>   frequently in speech and writing, in
>   which a syllable is substituted by an
>   apostrophe and/or other mode of
>   elision, e.g., can't for "cannot",
>   won't for "will not". Such
>   contractions are often either
>   negations with not or combinations of
>   pronouns with auxiliary verbs, e.g.,
>   I'll for "I will".

- The contractions (e.g. don't) and the full phrases (e.g. do not) have the **same meaning**.
- Contractions are **more frequent in speech than writing**.
- Contractions are **more frequent in informal than formal contexts**.
- It is not always the case that you can replace "don't" or "can't" etc. with "do not" or "cannot" directly; e.g. "Why can’t I?" (See nohat's comments below)

Comment: It is not always the case that you can replace *don’t* or *can’t* etc. with *do not* or *cannot* directly; e.g. there is no unawkward way to uncontract _Why can’t I?_

Comment: There is also a difference in the imperative form: "do not walk on the grass" is a better phrasing than "don't walk on the grass".

Comment: @Ether, why is "do not walk on the grass" better than "don't walk on the grass"? Is it the emphasis on "not"?

Comment: @nohat: awkwardness is in the ear of the beholder. Why can I not do that? It only sounds awkward because it's so seldom used.

Comment: @moioci “Why can I not do that?” is not “Why can’t I?” uncontracted. It is a different sentence. Uncontracted “Why can’t I?” is “Why cannot I?”, which is ungrammatical. You _might_ argue that “Why can I not?” is the uncontracted form, but like I said, it is pretty awkward. You could rephrase it to make it less awkward, but that’s entirely different from uncontracting.

Comment: @Bruno, "do not walk on the grass" comes across as both more emphatic and as more formal; so it's perhaps more likely to be taken seriously.

Comment: They have precisely the same meaning. However, there are some contexts where you are required to use the weak form ("Why *can't* I do that?") and some where you are required to use the strong form ("Are you as hungry as *I* *am*?").

Comment: I'm afraid that Wikipedia's wrong. Cliticization does not involve apostrophes; that's just a way we sometimes write cliticized words. Clitics are part of English, even for people who can't read or write, and always has been. With or without apostrophes.

Comment: "I can not sing" = "I'm capable to not sing", "I can't sing" = "I'm not capable to sing", no ?

Answer (score 1):

But don't you think that sometimes, "don't" works better than "do not"? "Do not" conveys an urgency or an order. While "don't" is not as pressing or commanding. For instance, I don't see your point of view." It could sound strange to force the argument by saying, "I do not see your point of view." Any thoughts on this?