# Is "could've" or "should've" standard English?

Tags: writing, slang, grammaticality, contractions

As the title says — is "could've" or "should've" standard English or is it slang and should correctly be spelled "could have" and "should have"?

Comment: Closely related, but not sure if I should consider it identical: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/difference-between-dont-and-do-not

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't replace that "have" with a preposition. Every time someone does that, an innocent kitten dies.

Comment: I have no use for kittens. I'm a vegetarian.

Comment: @RegDwight what do you have against "could of"?</sarcasm>

Comment: @C. Ross: as Germans say, I have nothing effective against it.

Comment: I'd much rather "could've" than the vomitus-inducing "could of".

Comment: Here's a better question... will we one day contract `could not have` : `couldn't've`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Contractions are generally considered *informal*, but have long been part of standard English. Because they are informal, most style guides—which tend to be guides for formal styles of written English—advise against using them. This of course makes sense, because if you are trying to write in a formal style, using informal words, like contractions, makes your writing seem less formal.

The [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/?c=coha&q=6418521) has incidences of *should’ve* dating to 1910, *could’ve* dating to 1880, and *would’ve* dating to 1830. A [Google Book Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=could%27ve%2BOR%2Bshould%27ve%2BOR%2Bwould%27ve&num=100&hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=orKkTOG8OoOC8gbY0omLAg&ved=0CBgQpwU&source=lnt&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1700,cd_max:12/31/1799) shows incidences of all three from 1800–1810.

For the record, *slang* is “very informal usage in vocabulary and idiom that is characteristically more metaphorical, playful, elliptical, vivid, and ephemeral than ordinary language.” Contractions with *have* are informal, sure, but they are also ordinary, and so are not really *slang*.

Answer (score 0):

Slang eventually becomes standardized, right?

Anyway, it's not incorrect to write them with the contractions. Writing could've and should've is standard, even if the spellcheckers say differently. The contractions just emphasize the pronunciation of the words.

Comment: I know it >>eventually<< becomes standardized, but is it standardized at the time we speak?

Comment: Um. _Some_ slang beconmes standardised. Most slang disappears and leaves no trace. And I'm sure there is some slang that stays around for a long time but remains slang, though I can't immediately think of an example.

Comment: As well as Colin's point, the shift between slang and standard is not necessarily unidirectional: the opposite can also happen, and what was once a standard, boring-sounding word can at a later stage in the language come to be perceived of as "slang".

Comment: Good point about the pronunciation. But it's not true to say it's "not incorrect" to use them. In formal (written) contexts, use of contractions is generally regarded as incorrect (acceptable *pronunciation* in formal situations may be another story!).