# Is contraction to <<noun>'s> proper English?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it grammatically correct to create a contraction of words followed by “is”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16797/when-is-it-grammatically-correct-to-create-a-contraction-of-words-followed-by-i)
>   [Using contracted forms (“don't”, “let's”) in a formal text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/using-contracted-forms-dont-lets-in-a-formal-text)
>   [Should contractions be avoided in formal emails?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/should-contractions-be-avoided-in-formal-emails)

My family was having the discussion after finding this (or something similar) in a book:

> The store's too far away.

Since this is being spoken, we're unsure whether it's proper English or slang.

Comment: "For the record, slang is 'very informal usage in vocabulary and idiom that is characteristically more metaphorical, playful, elliptical, vivid, and ephemeral than ordinary language.' Contractions [...] are informal, sure, but they are also ordinary, and so are not really slang." — from the top answer to [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/is-couldve-or-shouldve-standard-english) related question.

Answer (score 0):

It's frequently found in spoken English, but you wouldn't use it in formal writing unless you were writing dialogue. Is that how it appears in the book you were reading?

Comment: I think this is wrong. *NOUN + 's* is no more informal than any other contraction, so any writing form that admits contractions in general should allowthis.

Comment: My impression is that *-'s* for *is* or *has* is rarer than *-n't* for *not* in written English.