# Are there animacy restrictions on the use of contractions?

Tags: contractions, animacy

Are the examples (a) and (b) equally acceptable?

> (1a) That cop's very short and stout
>
> (1b) That cup's very short and stout

> (2a) Her spouse's been always attention-grabbing
>
> (2b) Her blouse's been always attention-grabbing

Comment: No problem with any of them. Auxiliaries will contract to whatever the subject is, noun or pronoun, animate or inanimate. Of course, the sound is different after _blouse_ than after _cop_, but that's not a problem.

Comment: "blouse's" might seem weird because the contraction is pronounced very similarly to the full "blouse is". But I don't think anyone would object to "Dinner's on the table" or the football chant "That coat's from Matalan".

Comment: What the others said. But your *always* is a bit clunky there. It's would be more natural after the first auxiliary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is contraction to _noun's_ proper English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/is-contraction-to-nouns-proper-english) [The store's too far away.]?

Answer (score 0):

Your (1a) and (1b) are fine.

Your (2a) and (2b) are equally unidiomatic; *always* is in the wrong slot.

Try:

> *Her spouse's always been attention-grabbing.*
>
> *Her blouse's always been attention-grabbing.*

Note that there is no need to *write* a contraction in the two sentences above. *Her spouse's always been* and *her spouse has always been* sound virtually identical in spoken English.

In fact, you should spell out *spouse has* to avoid a garden path situation where the reader anticipates, for example, *spouse's blouses* (possessive) or *spouse's lousy* (*is*, not *has*) along the way.