# Why is "doesn't" a legitimate starting word for a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-starts

*Doesn't* is the contraction for *does not*.

From my knowledge, the sentence *Doesn't Tom like Sally?* is legitimate.

Why is this so?

If I expand the sentence, it becomes *Does not Tom like Sally?* which starts to not make sense.

Comment: Even if the prescriptivists were to decree that it was wrong, using "doesn't" or "wouldn't" to start a sentence would persist in spite of the pissed P-ists, since it's simply the "not" of using "does" or "would", for the opposite sense, and is incredibly natural.

Comment: The phenomenon you're noticing is proof that *doesn't* is an independent word, not just a contraction of *does not*, even though it began as such a contraction.

Comment: "Doesn't is the contraction for does not" - Ah, yes. Now contrast `Doesn't Tom like Sally?` [I'm surprised Tom does not like Sally] with `Doesn't Tom like Sally!` [Get a bucket o'water...]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you say "are not we all?" instead of "aren't we all?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/67822/26083), which has links to several other related questions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The modern grammar requires that *not* must be contracted with the auxiliary verb in order to move from its normal position. If it is not contracted, it must stay in the same position it's in in a normal declarative sentence:

1. Tom does **not like Sally** (normal negative sentence)
2. Does Tom **not like Sally** (no contraction, *not* in normal declarative sentence position)
3. Does**n't** Tom **like Sally** (contracted with auxiliary, *n't* appears in pre-subject position)

Comment: +1 - Learning something new every day.

Comment: "Is not that so? It is." ( http://www.anselm.edu/homepage/dbanach/apology.htm )

Comment: See also: http://praxeology.net/alcibiades2.htm http://books.google.co.in/books?id=9vgrEwY3UBwC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22is+not+that+so%22+-%22isn%27t+that+so%22&source=bl&ots=6BT4Q_MVEf&sig=xQAcbKVrwwrTwksqSheCNjtK_5w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=s6lYVJDWBJHJuATF4YCQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22is%20not%20that%20so%22%20-%22isn%27t%20that%20so%22&f=false

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=JNZbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22is+not+that+so%22+-%22isn%27t+that+so%22&source=bl&ots=Zq8PNU3Jti&sig=LlrVSuF5xnJNKLXrI21DjmFGCZA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=s6lYVJDWBJHJuATF4YCQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22is%20not%20that%20so%22%20-%22isn%27t%20that%20so%22&f=false

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Took me awhile to understand it, but it was worth it :D

Answer (score 10):

I believe "Does not Tom like Sally" was actually a correct usage, though it is now uncommon/archaic except in the "Doesn't..." form. (I still hear "Does not..." occasionally when folks are attempting to be Extremely Formal, but that may be a back-formation.)

Comment: Indeed it was. For example, [Shakespeare](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/winters_tale/winters_tale.5.3.html): _I am ashamed: does not the stone rebuke me for being more stone than it?_

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't Tom like ..." and "Does Tom not like ..." are both correct. It is a feature of all contracted forms of auxiliary verbs used in the negative interrogative, e.g., "Wouldn't Tom like" or "Would Tom not like".

Comment: But the OP's example was "Does not Tom like", not "Does Tom not like"! :)

Comment: @Araucaria That's Martin's point.  The expanded form is *not* "Does not Tom like?", but rather "Does Tom not like?".  That's part of the contraction here.

Comment: @Nick2253 I don't understand what you mean :( "Doesn't Tom like" has [1: *Does* + 2: *n't* + 3 *Tom*]. Compare this with [1: *Does* + 3: *Tom* + 2: *not*]. The order of the parts is different when there is  or isn't a contraction. One is not a simple contraction of the other. That's the point of the question, imo:)

Comment: @Araucaria Contractions aren't just based on simple word order.  A feature of contractions in English in the negative interrogative is that word order isn't literal.  "Doesn't" in the negative interrogative is due to symmetry in the negative declarative "Tom does not like.." -> "Tom doesn't like..." -> "Doesn't Tom like...?"

Comment: @Nick2253 Yes, I know that (see answer below). My point was that Martin's answer sounded like it was affirmative: A & C are both correct. The OP's question was about A & B. But B nowadays, as pointed out by Keshlam below, is a bit squiffy!

Comment: "Doesn't Tom like Sally?" is not equivalent to "Does Tom not like Sally?".  If I answered yes (probably in the form of "yes, he does") to the first question, it would mean that Tom does like Sally.  If I answered yes (or more likely, "correct", or some other affirmative) to the second question, it would mean that Tom does not like Sally.