# Is there any difference on the use of I'm and I am?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to write I am Gerardo and I am here. 
or I am Gerardo and I'm here. Is there any difference between these two statements?

Comment: Please do not use an acute accent mark in lieu of an apostrophe.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/using-contracted-forms-dont-lets-in-a-formal-text), their meaning is semantically identical, but the contraction indicates informality relative to the non-contracted form.

As FumbleFingers mentions in another comment, "I am" has an additional attribute that "I'm" lacks. When "I am" is used as an affirmative response, it can imply an echo of the query:

Who is X?
I am. [Implying "I am X".]

Whereas "I'm" requires echoing the query:

Who is X?
I'm X.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, they're the same. But in many contexts they differ pragmatically. Imagine a large, though not very lavish, convention. Several mikes traverse the numerous audience, for which there aren't enough lights, so they're pretty much in the dark. Somebody takes the mike and says something truly interesting. The guests on stage squint and strain their necks trying to make out who it was. The spotlight hunts for its target as the voice resounds through the speakers: 'I am Gerardo and I'm here.' In that context, Gerardo is referring to his exact location. Now, if Gerardo happened to be a name notoriously known to belog to a public enemy, say, someone like Unabomber, and if his mere presence at the convention, say, in Washington DC, meant a threat par excellence, he'd be much more likely to have said: I am Gerardo and I am here. In that context, Gerardo is referring to his general presence at the convention, not to his exact location.

So, both the constructions have their distinctions, even if they be only pragmatic.

Answer (score -1):

No, both are same..I'm is the contracted form of : I am

This contracted form is used in informal communication..

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @ egrunin : You downvoted so you only explain..

Comment: (it was *my* downvote) No, they're not "the same". Among other differences, ***I'm*** is informal, and it's more common in speech than writing regardless of formality. Plus ***"I am"*** can stand alone as a two-word reply to a question (from someone asking whether you're a native speaker or not, for example). But you definitely *can't* simply reply ***"I'm"*** in such a context.

Comment: @ Fumble Fingers : Thanks for the explanation. Instead of downvoting, you could edit my answer... or post yours.. or could put this question on hold if you think it's a duplicate of the one you mentioned..

Comment: @egrunin : Sorry for blaming you to downvote my answer.. I mistook you as a downvoter..

Comment: In addition to what @FumbleFingers says, I'd say that it's a _contracted_ form if _I am_, not an _abbreviated_ form. And while the two may be the same in meaning, they are **not** the same in usage. As an example, I wouldn't proclaim: _"I think therefore I'm."_

Comment: @J.R.: Good example. Almost unavoidably, the stress there would have to be *"...therefore I **am**"*. As opposed to egruin's *"Who is X?", "**I** am."*, where the stress unavoidably falls on *"**I**"*. Essentially, you *can't* use the contracted form in any context where *either* of the two words takes stress.

Comment: A contraction is an abbreviation. And _I am_ is invariably stressed, and usually alone, in speech. If it's spoken normally, it's always _I'm_. So saying _I am_ in a normal sentence is already marking yourself as not a native speaker. In writing, you should write what you say, though people who paid too much attention in third grade find it hard to use contractions in writing.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree with you on all but one point: "I'm" is *not* an abbreviation. But I do agree that writing should reflect the natural rhythms/intonations of natural speech. I generally write "I'm" unless: the sentence is only two words (I am); I want emphatically stress the verb (I AM studying!); it's negative (I am not); or I want to change the rhythm of the sentence. Even the Chicago Manual of Style, the most conservative guide for AmE, recommends contraction use for most forms of writing (except for very formal academic work). Not using contractions sounds unnatural.