# What's the difference between "I'm" and "I am"?

Tags: grammar

I really wonder. Like, sometimes we use "I'm", and sometimes we use "I am".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference on the use of I'm and I am?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128405/is-there-any-difference-on-the-use-of-im-and-i-am)

Answer (score 2):

'I'm' is merely a contraction of 'I am'.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29):

> A contraction is a shortened version of the written and spoken forms
>   of a word, syllable, or word group, created by omission of internal
>   letters (actually, sounds). In traditional grammar, contraction can
>   denote the formation of a new word from one word or a group of words,
>   for example, by elision. This often occurs in rendering a common
>   sequence of words or, as in French, in maintaining a flowing sound.

'I'm' is always used in conjunction with a noun phrase. You cannot write "A boy, I'm", but you *can* write "A boy, I am". 'I'm' may also be considered informal outside speech or a literary scope.

'I am' is also longer to pronounce, and therefore has more emphasis (as pointed out by one of the answers).

Comment: And when would you use one form instead of another? Are there exceptions? Are they always interchangeable? Please, edit the post to make your answer appear more complete.

Comment: So add that to your answer. Make the answer full and complete in itself, without the need to refer to comments, and including any corroborative evidence you can find.

Comment: So, can you say **Yes, I'm.**?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, and I've pointed that out.

Comment: Not clearly enough. :) But now you have.

Answer (score 0):

Emphasis is the only difference I can think of in spoken English, besides "I am" sounding more formal. Also, there are those who say we should try to avoid the use of contractions in formal written English.

Yes, I'm going.

Yes, I **am** going.