# Is it okay to contract "dog is running" to "dog's running"?

Tags: contractions

Are the following contractions okay to use:

*The man's working on the roof* for *The man is working on the roof*
*The dog's running behind the ball* for *The dog is running behind the ball*

Comment: The contracted forms would be the norm in speech and light fiction say, but the full forms are required in formal writing.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Using contracted forms ("don't", "let's") in a formal text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/using-contracted-forms-dont-lets-in-a-formal-text). Certainly answered there; perhaps 'Acceptable to preferable in informal contexts' is only given by inference.