# Should we not use abbreviations at all in academic writing?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations, academia, academic-writing

I submitted a paper to a computer science conference, and the reviewer mentioned that I should correct grammar/writing issues throughout the paper.

Some of the things he/she mentioned:

don't -> do not

can't -> cannot

it's hard -> it is hard

So are abbreviations not welcomed in academic writing? If yes, then should I also change all aren't/isn't to are not/is not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using contracted forms ("don't", "let's") in a formal text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/using-contracted-forms-dont-lets-in-a-formal-text) // don't -> do not

can't -> cannot

it's hard -> it is hard (and on ELU he/she -> they).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, ok yeah, I got it.

Comment: In academic surroundings, talk like the people around you, and write like they write. If you don't know how they write, read some examples and get familiar with them. Otherwise, why are you doing writing for an academic audience?

Comment: Note that you're asking about **contractions**, not **abbreviations**.