# What is the correct usage of contractions like "isn't" and "wasn't"?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do contractions (e.g. “don't”) and full phrases (e.g. “do not”) have the same meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/do-contractions-e-g-dont-and-full-phrases-e-g-do-not-have-the-same-me)

I frequently see contractions such as "isn't" and "wasn't" used in sentences such as:

> Why wasn't she there?

Which would be equivalent to:

> Why was not she there?

Which doesn't make any sense. Considering how often I see this used I thought I could find something online about it, however I haven't had any luck.

Is it grammatically correct to use "isn't" and "wasn't" in sentences like the one above, and the one below? If so, why?

> Why isn't Dad home yet?

Comment: You might not like, "Why was not she there?" but I presume you'd have no problem with, "Why was she not there?"

Comment: @J.R. Correct. However I don't see how "Why wasn't she there" could expand to "Why was she not there". However if there is a reason, feel free to leave an answer :)

Comment: Isn't that acutally a fairly common usage from middle english? ... I'm asking.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: However, "Is it grammatically to use..." is not grammatical.

Comment: @GEdgar I fixed that already but thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: This has been discussed several times, though mostly in comments rather than in answers, e.g. [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/do-contractions-e-g-dont-and-full-phrases-e-g-do-not-have-the-same-me#comment4618_3236) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50251/is-it-incorrect-to-say-why-cannot#comment93184_50251). The gist of it is that your premise is false, "wasn't" simply is *not* equivalent to "was not".

Comment: @RegDwightΒВB Ah, okay. thank you.The answer to the first question you linked fully answers my question, so I'm flagging this to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I just deleted the answer I made below, so I can't comment on it there. I just reread [Zwicky and Pullum's 1983 paper](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/mrg.readings/ZPCliticsInfl.pdf) and realized they argue for _-n't_ having moved all the way from being a mere clitic to being a new inflectional suffix. So what I said there is wrong and I'll have to get back to it. That's why I deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, have a look at this ([source](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=8l0LAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA13&dq=%22is%20not%20she%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X1D7T4CDF5DtrQed5fjLBg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

[image]

Now, if you were to make contractions in these line, you would write:

- **Is not** she a fine creature? = **Isn't** she a fine creature?
- **Has not** she parts? = **Hasn't** she parts?
- **Is not** her beauty natural... = **Isn't** her beauty natural...

This kind of usage is now **archaic**. According, to this usage, you would simply write *isn't she* as *is not she*, *hasn't she* as *has not she*, and so on.

But nowadays, we use statements like:

- **Is she not** a fine creature?
- **Has she not** parts?
- **Is her beauty not** natural...

As you can see, now, "not" comes after the *subject*. For e.g.,

- **Isn't he** coming? = **Is *he* not** coming?
- **Hasn't she** done it? = **Has *she* not** done it?
- Why **hasn't he** come yet? = Why **has *he* not** come yet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the operation goes like this:
*start with:* She was not there.
*contraction:* She wasn't there.
*question:* Why wasn't she there?